# Where does the definition of "Tower of Algebras" come from?

Tags: ho.history-overview, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, co.combinatorics, operads

A *tower of algebras* is a sequence of algebras
$$A_0 \hookrightarrow A_1 \hookrightarrow \cdots \hookrightarrow A_n \hookrightarrow \cdots$$ 
with embeddings $A_n \otimes A_m \hookrightarrow A_{n+m}$ satisfying an associativity condition.

I found this definition recently in papers in representation theory such as:

"Algebraic structures on Grothendieck groups of a tower of algebras"
by Huilan Li and Nantel Bergeron
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612170

"Combinatorial Hopf algebras and Towers of Algebras - Dimension, Quantization, and Functoriality"
by Nantel Bergeron, Thomas Lam and Huilan Li
http://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.1381

"Representation theories of some towers of algebras related to the symmetric groups and their Hecke algebras"
by F. Hivert and N. Thiéry
http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/fpsac06/papers/75.pdf

Also, I found this definition in a homotopy theoretic (and operadic) paper:
"On Quillen homology and a homotopy completion tower for algebras over operads"
by J. Harper and K. Hess.

> My question is: where does the definition of tower of algebras come from and what was the original motivation to introduce this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit out of my comfort zone with this, but Goodman, de la Harpe and Jones "Coxeter graphs and towers of algebras" might be a place to start. The work here was motivated by questions about von Neumann algebras.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what the original motivation was (or where the original definition was). But one reasonable conceptual explanation for the definition is this: let $\mathcal C$ be a category with objects $\mathbb N$, endomorphisms $A_n$, and other morphism spaces 0. Then the embeddings $A_m \otimes A_n \to A_{m+n}$ (and the associativity conditions) are what is needed to provide $\mathcal C$ with a strict monoidal structure, where $m \otimes n := m + n$. Then one reason towers of algebras tend to be interesting is that monoidal categories tend to be interesting.

Comment: In particular, 1) the group algebras of the symmetric groups arise as a tower in this way with $C$ the free symmetric monoidal $k$-linear category on an object, 2) the group algebras of the braid groups arise as a tower in this way with $C$ the free braided monoidal $k$-linear category on an object, and 3) the Temperley-Lieb algebras arise as a tower in this way with $C$ the free monoidal $k$-linear category on a self-dual object.

Comment: Well, thank your setting and @QiaochuYuan examples (to which we could add deformations as the Hecke algebras, degenerate - no group, but a monoid there - or not :). Are there  good references where your categorical-skeletic ("$\mathcal C$ be a category with objects $\mathbb N$") is introduced and elaborated ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I right to say that it is only with the "external" multiplication $A_m \otimes A_n \rightarrow A_{m+n}$ (presumably this is  horizontal concatenation of diagrams in the case of a tower of planar algebras) that the graded vector space $H := \bigotimes_{n=0}^\infty  A_n/[A_n,A_n]$ acquires the structure of an associative, unital algebra; i.e. the "internal" multiplication coming from the inclusion maps $A_m \subset A_n \subset A_{m+n}$ (in the planar algebra case this would be mating  diagrams vertically) does not, in general, make $H$ into an algebra ?

Comment: I would guess that in general the maps $A_m\otimes A_n \to A_{m+n}$ are strictly more data than the inclusions $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$. As far as I know you need the first maps to make $H$ an algebra.